# Angular: how to load a svg file from a backend and use its content as a template?

Tags: angular, typescript, svg, angular-directive, angular-template

I need a way to load an SVG date from a Spring Boot backend and use its content as an Angular template.

My request currently looks like this:

```
   getSVG (): Observable <any> {
     return this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/path/to/svg/svg.svg`, {headers: new HttpHeaders ({'Content-Type': 'image/svg+xml'})});
   }
```

In my component it is called like this:

```
   ngOnInit () {
     this.myService.getSVG().subscribe((data) => {
       console.log('data', data);
     });
   }
```

The request goes through so that I get the svg file in the network tab. But in the browser console I get the following error message:

```
backend returned code 200, body was: [object Object]           main.js:1388:25
    intercept http://localhost:8425/main.js:1388
    error http://localhost:8425/vendor.js:223317
    onLoad http://localhost:8425/vendor.js:41005
    invokeTask http://localhost:8425/polyfills.js:663
    onInvokeTask http://localhost:8425/vendor.js:76954
    invokeTask http://localhost:8425/polyfills.js:662
    runTask http://localhost:8425/polyfills.js:431
    invokeTask http://localhost:8425/polyfills.js:744
    invokeTask http://localhost:8425/polyfills.js:1885
    globalZoneAwareCallback http://localhost:8425/polyfills.js:1922


ERROR OK                                                       vendor.js:47101:33
    defaultErrorLogger http://localhost:8425/vendor.js:47101
    handleError http://localhost:8425/vendor.js:47153
    next http://localhost:8425/vendor.js:77725
    schedulerFn http://localhost:8425/vendor.js:73301
    __tryOrUnsub http://localhost:8425/vendor.js:219977
    next http://localhost:8425/vendor.js:219916
    _next http://localhost:8425/vendor.js:219866
    next http://localhost:8425/vendor.js:219843
    next http://localhost:8425/vendor.js:219629
    emit http://localhost:8425/vendor.js:73263
    onHandleError http://localhost:8425/vendor.js:77012
    invoke http://localhost:8425/polyfills.js:628
    run http://localhost:8425/polyfills.js:387
    runOutsideAngular http://localhost:8425/vendor.js:76893
    onHandleError http://localhost:8425/vendor.js:77009
    handleError http://localhost:8425/polyfills.js:632
    runTask http://localhost:8425/polyfills.js:434
    invokeTask http://localhost:8425/polyfills.js:744
    invoke http://localhost:8425/polyfills.js:733
    timer http://localhost:8425/polyfills.js:2816
```

I would like to extract the content of the SVG and use it in my template, like:

**my.component.svg**

```
<svg width="400" height="110">
  <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
    ...
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't define a component in browser after got the template from network. An angular component is compiled together with the template which should be existed at compile time. If you really want to insert a dynamic svg content, you can use 'innerHtml' after you got the svg file from http request. See https://www.chrisjmendez.com/2017/06/17/angular-dynamically-inserting-svg-into-an-element/